# Angular filter for specific properties in an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I have an angular filter by input text.
 for the given list

```
initialViewModel.users = [
{user: 'Nithin',phone: 'Azus', price: 13000}, 
{user: 'Saritha',phone: 'MotoG1',price: 12000}, 
{user: 'Renjith',phone: 'MotoG2',price: 14000}, 
{user: 'Felix',phone: 'Nexus',price: 21000}];
```

It is returning incorrect results for the filter texts `a,g,m,n,o,s,u,z`.

[Sample fiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/895tawc0/)

```
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="user in Model.users | filter: Model.name | orderBy:'price'">{{user.user + ' bought phone worth ' + user.price}}</li>
        </ul>
```

Say for example, if I filter it with 'a' it should return only the one record having name saritha. Instead it returns two records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default angular filters by any property of an object. If you want to filter by specific property you need to update your filter:

```
<li ng-repeat="user in Model.users | filter: { user: Model.name } | orderBy:'price'">
    {{user.user + ' bought phone worth ' + user.price}}
</li>
```

Pay attention to this part: `filter: { user: Model.name }`. In this case you are telling angular to filter only property `user` of your object.

Here is an [updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/895tawc0/1/)

Comment: yeah. That's it. Thanks a bunch.