# AngularJS filter by "concat" several data?

Tags: php, html, angularjs

I'm using angularJS for **tables**, and one of the columns is a specific "id" which is caught from

```
 <tr ng-repeat="x in stock | filter:Filter">
 <td>{{x.ean}}{{x.date| date:'ddMM'}}{{x.brand| limitTo : 3 : begin}}</td>
```

that will return a value like "12342703ABC"

Fine with that, I also have a search input

```
<b>Filter:</b> <input type="text" ng-model="Filter" id="Filter">
```

when I use it it will search on every column, but I'd need it also to filter if I write that specific "id" (f.e 12342703ABC) on the input, which is not happening.

any ideas?

Comment: Are you getting any errors that are preventing it from working?

Comment: You should check out first if you are using angular or angularJs ;)

Comment: I think it filters `x` **before** any formatting is applied, you can try to format it first (in the controller) and then use the result for searching with your filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of 2 solutions

1) Create a new property called id that contains the result of

```
{x.ean}}{{x.date| date:'ddMM'}}{{x.brand| limitTo : 3 : begin}}
```

expression in your controller and add these newly created property to your list. If you use the above method your current filter would work.

```
   angular.forEach($scope.data, function(value, key){
     //{{x.ean}}{{x.date| date:'ddMM'}}{{x.brand| limitTo : 3 : begin}}
        var date = new Date(value.date);
        var day = date.getDate()
        var month = date.getMonth()+ 1;

        value.id = value.ean; 

        if(day < 10)
          value.id = value.id + "0"+ day;
        else
          value.id = value.id + day;

        if(month < 10)
          value.id = value.id + "0" + month;
        else
          value.id = value.id + month;

        value.id = value.id + value.brand.substring(0,3);
   });
```

2) create a custom filter

```
   $scope.myCustomFilter = function(row){

        if($scope.Filter == undefined || $scope.Filter.length == 0){
          return true;
        }
        else{
                  var data = "";
        var date = new Date(row.date);
        var day = date.getDate()
        var month = date.getMonth()+ 1;

        data = data + row.ean; 

        if(day < 10)
          data = data + "0"+ day;
        else
          data = data + day;

        if(month < 10)
          data = data + "0" + month;
        else
          data = data + month;

        data = data + row.brand.substring(0,3);

     if(data.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.Filter.toLowerCase()) >= 0)
        return true;
      else 
        return false;
        }
   }
```

**[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/4qWB0NuWvecJb9SUjZrO?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in stock | filter:{id: Filter}">
 <td>{{x.ean}}{{x.date| date:'ddMM'}}{{x.brand| limitTo : 3 : begin}}</td>
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32449638/angular-filter-for-specific-properties-in-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should `ng-init` `x.specificId` and then use it in HTML. This field also will be taken into account by `filter`:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.begin = 0;
    $scope.stock = [    
      {ean:'1234', brand:'brand1', date: new Date()},
      {ean:'5678', brand:'brand2', date: new Date()},
      {ean:'9012', brand:'brand3', date: new Date()}
    ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller="ctrl">
  <input type='text' ng-model='Filter' />
  <ul ng-repeat="x in stock | filter : Filter" ng-init="x.specificId = x.ean + (x.date | date:'ddMM') + (x.brand | limitTo : 3 : begin)">
    <li>{{x.specificId}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```